# How to embed Jquery script in Java Selenium code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, jquery

I am automating a process a process where I need to download csv files from a website.

I have written a jquery code for that. Can someone tell me how can i integrate this code with my Java selenium code.

a.java

```
package package1;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.Log;

public class Noofrowsandcols {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, InterruptedException {
WebDriver wd;
String exepath="C:\\Users\\sh370472\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\chromedriver.exe";
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exepath);
 wd= new ChromeDriver();
 wd.get("https://www.shipper-ml.com");
 wd.findElement(By.id("inpUserId")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
 wd.findElement(By.id("inpPassword")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
 wd.findElement(By.id("btnLogonLabel")).click();
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 wd.get("https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do");  

 }

}
```

b.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).load(function () {
$('.ibody tr').each(function (a, b) {
var count=0;
var name = $('.cl', b).text();
if(name.indexOf(".CSV")!==-1 && name.indexOf("TAS")!==-1){
var d= a-9;
var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader' + count++;
var iframe = window.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
iframe.style.display = 'none';
window.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = "https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do? 
ctrl=reportListForDownload&action=DownloadReport&param="+d;

}
});
```

});
   });

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) wd;
 js.executeScript("$(document).ready(function () {
 $(window).load(function () {
 $('.ibody tr').each(function (a, b) {
 var count=0;
  var name = $('.cl', b).text();
  if(name.indexOf(".CSV")!==-1 && name.indexOf("TAS")!==-1){
  var d= a-9;
  var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader' + count++;
  var iframe = window.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  window.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.src = "https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do?ctrl=reportListForDownload&action=DownloadReport&param="+d;

      }
        });
    });
```

});     ")));

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery is a library, to run jQuery hmm.. queries.. you have to have it embedded to your page first of all. See the details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp). That basically means that you cannot take just any page and run jQuery-based code there.

After you have made sure your page loads jQuery library, you can execute jQuery javascript in a regular way that Selenium provides. Find the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-java).

Comment: My Jquery code runs perfectly in inspect console of that website page.

Comment: Great! Then use `JavascriptExecutor` to run your code.

Comment: Can you please help me with it as I don't know how to integrate jquery using JavascriptExecutor ?

Comment: I have updated the code with JavascriptExecutor ... Can you please tell me if it's correct or should I do something else also ?

Comment: Your script is a string. You should put your script into a `String` object. Basically that means to wrap your script into double quotes.

Comment: I have updated the code . Can you please tell me if this is what you are talking about ?